# Fontspec pb since update May 20th, 2013 on MiKTeX2.9 and Win7(32bit)

Tags: luatex, fontspec

When I want to compile the file `fonspec-example.tex` with the latest version 2.3c of `fontspec`, I get an error (It didn't happen before):

`fonspec.lua:45:attempt to call upvalue 'check_script' (a nil value)`

error seems to come from line 45 in fontspec.lua:
function fontspec.check_ot_script(fnt, script)

Anybody knows how that can be solved?
Thx.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.sx! Feel free to visit our [TeX.SX starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to get th emost out of our site.

Comment: Miktex will revert to an older fontspec soon. (The newest version doesn't work with the luatex version of miktex and luatex will be updated only later this year.).

Comment: @ulrike-fischer perhaps that will be unnecessary. I [added](https://github.com/lualatex/luaotfload/commit/830a0fa4481fba007af873ea4ec18451e1806aee) the functionality that was removed from fontspec to legacy luaotfload yesterday. Unfortunately I can’t really test them because the latex3 packages in TL2012 are too old for current fontspec.

Comment: @phg This seems to work if used together will all the newest version from TL13. But I wouldn't invest to much time in compability code. As soon as miktex updates the binary it will no longer be necessary and until then miktex can simply avoid to update lua packages.

Answer (score 0):

I removed the file fontspec.lua from the folder C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\fontspec and replaced it by an older file (dated 16/03/2013) from another computer. 
While waiting for an update that corrects the bug, this works.